# Python - How to Compare a column value of one row with value in next row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare the S.No. of different rows, if it is same then I want to calculate the datetime difference and print details.(If datetime difference is not possible then only date difference would also be fine.)

Input

```
S.No.   Datetime    Details

1    2010/6/7 19:01 asd 

1    2010/6/8 4:00  dfg 

2    2010/6/9 0:00  dfg 

2   2010/6/10 0:00  gfd 

2   2010/6/11 0:00  gfd 

3   2010/6/12 0:00  gfd 

3   2010/6/13 0:00  abc 

4   2010/6/14 0:00  abc 

4   2010/6/15 0:00  def
```

Expected output

```
1   0.3 asd dfg

2   1   dfg gfd

2   1   gfd gfd

3   1   gfd abc

4   1   abc def
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts and what the desired output looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Assume your input is saved in a pandas Dataframe (or equivalently save it into csv and read it using pandas.read_csv).
Now you can loop over the groups with same S.No values with the following:

```
output = {}

for key, group in df.groupby('S.No.'):
#   print key
#   print group

   output[key] = {}
   output[key]['Details'] = group['Details'].values.tolist()
   output[key]['Date Time Diff'] = pd.to_datetime(group['Datetime']).diff().iloc[-1]
```

Output of the above

```
1 {'Date Time Diff': Timedelta('0 days 08:59:00'), 'Details': ['asd', 'dfg']}
2 {'Date Time Diff': Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00'), 'Details': ['dfg', 'gfd', 'gfd']}
3 {'Date Time Diff': Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00'), 'Details': ['gfd', 'abc']}
4 {'Date Time Diff': Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00'), 'Details': ['abc', 'def']}
```

Comment: Thanks Flab, groupby is working. Its a great help, since I have worked on C so my approach was totally different. I have big data, if I am using print statement then I am again getting stuck so I am thinking of passing values to a new dataframe and then write that df to csv file.

Comment: This is how I tried but its not working                                                                            for key, group in df.groupby('S.No.')                                                             a.append(group)                                                                                            I also tried a.iloc(group) but either I am getting empty dataframe or just the repeatetion of header...

Comment: Updated answer to show possible implementation. If you have big data, you might want to find a way to optimize...